# Execution of logging debug only on certain global condition

Tags: python, debugging

I have statements for debugging like:
logging.debug('outputs from scan:',outputs[0])
The thing is outputs doesn't exist until a flag is True.
So, even if logging.Level is not debug, it does execute this line though it won't save.

Is it possible to execute this statement only when flag is True .

I want to avoid checking flag before every debug statement but instead these debug statements shouldn't be executed at all at runtime to deal with this scenario.

Comment: I don't know enough about your problem to give a definitive answer, but why not just make a `log_outputs` function? `def log_outputs(): if some_flag: logging.debug(...)`

Comment: I have such statements all over the code and with different arguments.Currently, I am checking `flag` before every    logging.debug. I want to avoid those multiple checks with some central check. To use: `def  log_outputs()` I would need to pass the args which exist only when `flag is True` which is similar to before.

Comment: Ah, so is the issue that you don't know whether `outputs` will be defined or not?

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly advise against working in a situation in which you don't know whether variables are defined or not. Having said that, if you have a use-case for it, Python will provide.

What I'd probably do here is wrap up the calls to logging.debug behind a callable. Again, I'm not sure what your use-case is, but here's a brief proof-of-concept.

```
import logging

some_condition = True
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def lazy_log(callable):
    if logging.getLogger('').isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
        logging.debug(callable())

def main():
    if some_condition:
        outputs = [1,2,3,4]
    lazy_log(lambda: "Outputs from scan: {}".format(outputs[1]))

main()
```

By using a `lambda`, we defer computation of the logging string until we know we need it. This also has the advantage that if I want to make a debug log with a really slow thing, like a database query, I won't slow my production program down at all with my debug statements.

I got bored on a train so I turned this thing into a library; https://github.com/Ymbirtt/python-lazylog. I've not used it for anything yet, but it might save you a bit of work.